# Docker container fails to start because of missing SMB drive and doesn't restart automatically when connected

Tags: docker, samba, smb

I have a Docker container that uses an SMB drive as a volume. This is the compose file for it:

```
name: "audiobookshelf"
services:
  audiobookshelf:
    container_name: "audiobookshelf"
    restart: always
    image: ghcr.io/advplyr/audiobookshelf:latest
    privileged: false
    environment: []
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - "13378:80"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /media/patataos/barracuda4/audiobooks
        target: /audiobooks
      - type: bind
        source: /app/audiobookshelf/config
        target: /config
      - type: bind
        source: /app/audiobookshelf/metadata
        target: /metadata
```

The SMB drive in question is mounted on boot with:

```
//192.168.1.2/patataos /media/patataos cifs nofail,x-systemd.automount,vers=3.1.1,credentials=/media/.patataos_credentials
```

My issue is that it seems that either the docker container tries to start before the actual share is mounted, thus failing and doesn't try again or that the drive is lazily mounted and it doesn't mount unless I manually try to access it through a terminal. I was under the impression that with `restart: always` Docker would actually keep trying to restart it but despite manually mounting the drive the container doesn't seem to come up by itself. I believe I need either a way to ensure that the drive is actually mounted or to understand why Docker's access request doesn't count for lazy mounting the drive.

Comment: That’s not what `restart: always` means. // Consider that the Docker daemon is highly likely to start before even the _autofs_ is mounted.